# Chrome overrides add file manually

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I have a production (for specific site) JavaScript file which I'm overwriting (using Chrome Overrides) with my local development version. I wrote a script that watches for changes in my local files and then copies files to my overrides folder. It is working fine. However local development JavaScript file have source maps (from TypeScript attached to them), which I'm copying to overrides folder too. However despite of file `myScript.js.map` being present in overrides directory right next to `myScript.js`, Chrome still tries to download `myScript.js.map` from remote server instead of my local overrides folder.
I guess it happens because I didn't actually modified such file in sources tab. Is there any way to force Chrome to load files (not directly modified in sources tab of dev tools) from my local overrides directory instead of remote server?

Comment: Interesting, so you local override `myScript.js` in DevTools, and you want to load `myScript.js.map` locally as well because you want to debug the file?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the js file in the Sources panel, you can add sourcemap url. [image: Add sourcemap URL]